# How to predict employee's attendance based on previous attendance

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, python, prediction

I am using [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/) website to learn Machine Learning. I am working on a simple project to learn it.  I want to predict employee's attendance.  This is the data in the file:

```
1,0,1,0,1,0,John
```

The index of the columns is the day number.  `John` is the name of the employee.  `1` means that he came to work, and `0` means he didn't.  So according to these data:

```
Day 1: 1
Day 2: 0
Day 3: 1
Day 4: 0
Day 5: 1
Day 6: 0
```

I want to predict day number 7 based on the previous days.  I am expecting that there is a chance that 100% John will come in day number 7.  Because it seems to be a pattern that every day he comes on the odd days.

I want to be able to tell the probability he will come.  The above example is easy for learning, but it can be more complex:

```
Day 1: 1
Day 2: 0
Day 3: 1
Day 4: 1
Day 5: 1
Day 6: 0
...
Day 49: 1
Day 50: 1
```

Back to the first example, I added the information to a dataset:

```
import pandas
url = r'C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\employee.txt'
names = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', 'class']
dataset = pandas.read_csv(url, names=names)
dataset
```

This the result:

[image]

But I don't know how to get the prediction.  I want it to tell me "the chance that John will come on day 7 based on his previous attendance".

Comment: I'll write an example!

Comment: This is too broad at present to be well answerable here. In essence, you need a complete course on time series & forecasting. You might try reading through the many threads we already have categorized under the [tag:forecasting] tag, & see if you can learn enough to ask a more specific, answerable question.

Comment: @gung I will try to make it more accurate but I am not sure I succeed because maybe like you wrote I need first to have more knowledge. I will check first regarding the forecasting tag you mentioned. I asked this question because I thought it might be simple to answer.

Comment: @Lejafar if you can put in comment the example via link of https://pastebin.com/ untill I finish to edit the question (it will take time) it can be great, thanks !

Comment: @E235 here it is https://gist.github.com/lejafar/da2c95b671df6cb1597fc44a07f312be, I have no experience with proper sequence learning but here is my intuitive approach using using the n-previous values in the sequence. I can elaborate more when the question is opened again. It might still contain some bugs but it seems to work fine, its able to complete the example sequences.

Comment: @Lejafar thanks, I really appreciate your help. When I run your tests I received `([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], ' prediction: ', 0, ', should be:', 1)
([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], ' prediction: ', 0, ', should be:', 1)
([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], ' prediction: ', 0, ', should be:', 0)
([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], ' prediction: ', 0, ', should be:', 1)`
It seems that the prediction in all of them was 0 instead of 1, isn't it a problem ?

Comment: Strange, when I run it (python3), I get: `[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]  prediction:  1 , should be: 1 [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]  prediction:  1 , should be: 1 [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]  prediction:  0 , should be: 0
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]  prediction:  1 , should be: 1`

Comment: I changed some things and now it makes a lot more sense, the predicted following value is now based on the most certain pattern i.e. one that has least been wrong. @gung I would like to answer the question "the chance that John will come on day 7 based on his previous attendance" in a way that avoids a course on time series and approaches the problem intuitively ...

Answer (score 3):

*The example I'm about to give avoids the use of proper sequence learning and instead goes for a simple and hopefully more intuitive attribute-value approach based on the [Naive Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) estimator. There are more advanced ways of solving this but from reading your question I think the approach I'm about to present is more appropriate.*

So given what we know about the previous sequence, we want to learn **as much as possible** about what is about to follow. Let's take the following sequence `[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]`:

Based on the last value, `1`, we can say that in **4 out of 6 cases**, a `0` will follow. The same can be done for the previous 2 values, `0,1`;  these are in **2 out of 3 cases** followed by a `1`. The same can be said about the previous 3 values, `1,0,1`, which are in **2 out of 3 cases** followed by a `1`. Now looking at the previous 4 values `1,1,0,1` we can finally state that this will **always** be followed by a `0`,idem for the previous 5 and 6.  We don't know anything about the previous 7 as they have not been seen before. A natural conclusion is thus the follow the prediction based on the most certain predictions based on the previous 4,5 and 6 values and state that `0` be the next value.

One can thus parse all patterns of length `n` from the sequence:

```
def parse(history, n):
    for i in range(len(history) - n):
        yield (history[i:i + n], history[i + n])
```

Which will yield for `n=3`:

```
[([1, 0, 1], 1),
 ([0, 1, 1], 0),
 ([1, 1, 0], 1),
 ([1, 0, 1], 0),
 ([0, 1, 0], 1),
 ([1, 0, 1], 1),
 ([0, 1, 1], 0),
 ([1, 1, 1], 1)]
```

Next step is to learn from these patterns how many times a certain pattern is followed by `1` or `0`

```
def learn(example, n):
    occurences = parse(example, n)
    # counts[followed_by][pattern]
    counts = [[0] * pow(2, n), [0] * pow(2, n)]
    # loop over all occurences
    for occurence in occurences:
        pattern, followed_by = occurence
        pattern_hash = hash(pattern)
        counts[followed_by][pattern_hash] += 1
    return counts
```

In the above we hash each pattern into the its binary value for convenience. We can now determine the probability the previous-n values (i.e. last n-values of our example) are followed by a `1`

```
def probability(example, n):
    counts = learn(example, n)
    # determine probability that 1 will follow after `previous`
    # (last n values), using what we know about past values
    previous = example[-n:]
    previous_hash = hash(previous)
    # Determine probability of `followed_by`=1
    total_count = (counts[1][previous_hash] + counts[0][previous_hash])
    # if pattern was never (`total_count` == 0) seen return None
    return counts[1][previous_hash] / total_count if total_count else None
```

The last step is to make a prediction based on the most certain prediction between the different pattern lengths `n` from the previous step. `probability([1,0,1,1,0,1,0], 3)` will return `None` as `0,1,0` has never been observed, `probability([1,0,1,1,0,1,0], 2)` will return 3/4.

```
def prediction(example):
    max_n = len(example) - 1
    # Determine probability of `followed_by`=1 over different pattern lengths
    probabilities = [(probability(example, n), n) for n in range(1, max_n) if probability(example, n) is not None]
    # If min equals 0, there is a pattern that is inconsistent with next being 1
    p = min(probabilities)[0] and max(probabilities)[0]
    n = [n for pp, n in probabilities if pp==p][0]
    most_informative = example[-n:] + [int(p)]
    return (p, most_informative)
```

When one of the probabilities equals zero, which means that a `1` would be fully inconsistent with a certain pattern, the probability is zero. When one of the probabilities equals one, this means that a `1` is in perfect agreement with a certain pattern and the probability for `1` is thus one.

As an extra feature the last step will also give the most informative pattern, in the case of equal importance, the shortest is returned. The following tests show it in action:

```
tests = [([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 1),
         ([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 1),
         ([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], 0),
         ([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 1)]
# run tests
for test in tests:
    pattern, expectation = test
    outcome, mi = prediction(pattern)
    test_outcome = "CORRECTLY" if outcome == expectation else "INCORRECTLY"
    print("Predicted", int(outcome),
          test_outcome,"for", pattern, ", pattern:", mi)

>>> Predicted 1 CORRECTLY for [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] , pattern: [0, 1]
>>> Predicted 1 CORRECTLY for [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] , pattern: [0, 1]
>>> Predicted 0 CORRECTLY for [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] , pattern: [0, 1, 0]
>>> Predicted 1 CORRECTLY for [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] , pattern: [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

The full code can be found [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/lejafar/da2c95b671df6cb1597fc44a07f312be)

Comment: it looks great ! I am checking why `pattern = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]` return  `(0, [0, 0])`. It was supposed to be `1`. I am also trying to see how to show it as precentages. I will update your answer once done, thanks.

Comment: When using **python3** it works as expected `Predicted 1 CORRECTLY for [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0] , pattern: [0, 0, 1]`, I probably used some built-in function that had slightly different functionality in python2

Comment: oh OK, great. I will re-check. Thanks ! much appreciate your answer.